# Copy a slice of i32 pixels into an [u8] slice

Tags: rust

How to copy a row of pixels in an `i32` slice into an existing slice of pixels in an `[u8]` slice ?

Both slices are in the same memory layout (i.e. RGBA) but I don't know the unsafe syntax to copy one efficiently into the other. In C it would just be a memcpy().

Comment: The `memcpy` way keeps little-endian format, is that what you intend? It seems more likely you would like to keep the R-G-B-A order, which requires endianess manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the order and just copy the memory without having to re-map the memory before copying.

Comment: Well, the endianness is an issue if the `i32` values come from a file or a network resource. But if they came from an in-process resource, then maybe the `memcpy` method is correct.

Comment: Yes it comes from an a live renderer and I need to copy the memory to the [u8] surface, just need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you in fact do not need any byte reordering, the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/) library is the tool to use here, as it allows you to write the i32 to u8 reinterpretation without needing to consider safety (because `bytemuck` has checked it for you).

Specifically, [`bytemuck::cast_slice()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/fn.cast_slice.html) will allow converting `&[i32]` to `&[u8]`.

(In general, the function may panic if there is an alignment or size problem, but there never can be such a problem when converting to `u8` or any other one-byte type.)

Comment: Thanks for this, works like a charm and I do not need to convert the pixels first.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) the byte representation of each `i32` into a `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let pixels: &[i32] = &[-16776961, 16711935, 65535, -1];
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = pixels
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|e| e.to_ne_bytes())
        .collect();

    println!("{bytes:?}");
}
```

There are different ways to handle the endianess of the system, I left [`to_ne_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_ne_bytes) to preserve the native order, but there are also [`to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_le_bytes) and [`to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_be_bytes) if that is something that needs to be controlled.

Alternatively, if you know the size of your pixel buffer ahead of time, you can use an `unsafe` [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html):

```rust
const BUF_LEN: usize = 4; // this is your buffer length

fn main() {
    let pixels: [i32; BUF_LEN] = [-16776961, 16711935, 65535, -1];
    let bytes = unsafe {
        std::mem::transmute::<[i32; BUF_LEN], [u8; BUF_LEN * 4]>(pixels)
    };

    println!("{bytes:?}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there no way to copy the memory without re-ordering ?

Comment: @MarkusMoenig yeah, you can use `to_le_bytes` instead of `to_be_bytes` if you want little-endian, or `to_ne_bytes` to keep whatever the default is on the local machine

Comment: Ok, but I want to copy the memory into the destination memory in one step without converting it first ...

Comment: @MarkusMoenig The only to do that is to use `unsafe`, and I'm not sure the best way to do that with slices since `transmute`s and pointer casts need a constant array size to prevent loss of data. You might want to add those details to your question.

Comment: I know the size of the slice if that helps …

Comment: @MarkusMoenig I added a second example showing how you can use `transmute` if you know the size of your pixel buffer. again, this only works for constants, but it sounds like this may be what you are looking for